# how redirect users to custom login page when user comment must “login to reply” is clicked?

Tags: redirect, links

I am building my website on Wordpress and I have created my custom login page.But for a post when an user comments and other nonlogged see the comment with along with a line down "Login to reply".And when the user clicks on that"Login" from "Login to reply" it redirects to wp-login.php.So how to redirect users to custom login page when "login to reply" for a post is clicked on wordpress instead of wp-login.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `functions.php` file or in a plugin file-

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse_290288_custom_login_url', 10, 3 );
function wpse_290288_custom_login_url( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    $login_page_id = 123; // ID of your custom login page
    return get_permalink( $login_page_id );
}
```

Comment: wow! Code  working Sir ThankYou So Much For The Help Sir,

Comment: Nice to hear that @MuhammadShahzeb. In that case, you should mark this answer as "selected". See this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G4f3.png